# Where's the documentation for Ctrl-C while in [Command Line] buffer?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, ex-mode, help-system

Long ago I discovered that <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> opens a `[Command Line]` buffer where I can enter and edit an ex command line using all the power of Vim.

Next, some time ago, I discovered that I can access that mode even while in the middle of editing a command line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

For all the above I've found the doc.

But today, I've discovered that hitting <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> while *in that* window, the line being edited is copied on the ex prompt which becomes active. It's a bit like it's the inverse of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

However, I couldn't find the documentation for it. Can you enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, type `:h q:`. It takes you to the file `cmdline.txt` near the top of the section #7 "Command-line window".

The whole section is, obviously, 100% relevant to the topic. The `<C-C>` keybinding is mentioned a pair of page-downs under.

Speaking in general, there are 3 main ways:

1. Press F1. Then scroll down to "REFERENCE MANUAL". Find relevant help file. Browse through the contents, use `/`, `n`, `N` etc. Probably, this is too boring, but I had to mention this.
2. If you clearly remember something that **must be** tagged, such as `:command` then type `:h :command` (also, make some use of "tab"-completion), look around, follow the links with `<C-]>` and `<C-T>` etc.

And even when you're not sure, just naive typing `:h something` could help you a lot.

3. If you still have no idea then go with `:h :helpgrep`.

Answer (score 1):

After `:help q:` and scrolling down a bit:

```
CLOSE                           *E199*

There are several ways to leave the command-line window:

<CR>        Execute the command-line under the cursor.  Works both in
        Insert and in Normal mode.
CTRL-C      Continue in Command-line mode.  The command-line under the
        cursor is used as the command-line.  Works both in Insert and
        in Normal mode.  There is no redraw, thus the window will
        remain visible.
:quit       Discard the command line and go back to Normal mode.
        ":close", CTRL-W c, ":exit", ":xit" and CTRL-\ CTRL-N also
        work.
:qall       Quit Vim, unless there are changes in some buffer.
:qall!      Quit Vim, discarding changes to any buffer.

Once the command-line window is closed the old window sizes are restored.  The
executed command applies to the window and buffer where the command-line was
started from.  This works as if the command-line window was not there, except
that there will be an extra screen redraw.
The buffer used for the command-line window is deleted.  Any changes to lines
other than the one that is executed with <CR> are lost.

If you would like to execute the command under the cursor and then have the
command-line window open again, you may find this mapping useful: >

    :autocmd CmdwinEnter * map <buffer> <F5> <CR>q:
```